# Jquery- How to use contains here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contains

How would I use contains to search for a placeholder to search for the word "name" and set the value rather than search the exact value of a placeholder.

*Here is the html:*

```
      <input autocorrect="off" placeholder="full name here" id="order_billing_name" name="order[billing_name]" size="30" class="" type="text">
```

*How would I use contains to search for "name" and set the value rather than searching for the exact value "full name here"*

```
 $('[placeholder="full name here"]').val('name here');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute value contains selector

```js
$("[placeholder*=name]").val("name here")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input autocorrect="off" 
       placeholder="full name here" 
       id="order_billing_name" 
       name="order[billing_name]" 
       size="30" 
       class="" 
       type="text">
```

Comment: You are awesome. This is exactly what I needed :D